# Eclipse auto-build output interacts with Maven command-line build output

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

Since both use the target directory, Eclipse's build output sometimes interferes with the output of mvn builds run at the command line.

What's the best way to separate the two outputs?

Comment: I have an answer for this question but can't yet submit it due to stackoverflow's restrictions - will post in eight hours

Comment: I'm working with Maven/Eclipse in combination and have no problems with auto compilation etc. What is the problem?

Comment: @khmarbaise - the problem is that when CLI Maven cleans the target directory, Eclipse automatically starts repoopulating it, which can then interfere with CLI Maven's operation

Comment: only if you have configured Eclipose to automatically repopulate. In my case i need to manually refresh...

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like Eclipse to poll the filesystem, so that's why this is necessary for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Insert the following into your pom.xml. Eclipse's "m2e.version" property will activate the following profile which alters the location of the Eclipse build

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>IDE</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>m2e.version</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <build>
      <!-- Put the IDE's build output in a folder other than target, so that IDE builds don't interact with Maven builds -->
      <directory>target-ide</directory>
    </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

Official way is presented here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_FAQ#How_to_configure_Maven_project_to_use_separate_output_folders_in_Eclipse

I personally don't do something like this. Usually I basically disable auto-build in Eclipse since most builds I do from the console anyway. But if you really want it, here you are.

Comment: Thanks Michal. My approach is to use a profile that sets a different build directory, activated by the existence of the m2e.version property. Thus no alteration required to Eclipse project properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you use maven-eclipse-plugin instead of M2Eclipse, here's the definition you want in order to change the Eclipse output directory:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <buildOutputDirectory>target-eclipse/classes</buildOutputDirectory>
    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```